# Generating code during execution in c++11

Tags: c++

I am programming with C++11 and was wondering if there is a way to generate some code during execution.

For example instead of writing:

```
void b(int i){i+1}
void c(int i){i-1}
if(true) b()
else{ c() }
```

would there be a more straightforward way to say if true, then replace all + with - ?

Thank you and sorry if this question is stupid..

Comment: You could rewrite the function to accept a `bool` parameter for example: `void b(int i, bool j) { return i + (j ? 1 : -1); }`. This doesn't need run-time code generation.

Comment: No, there is no way. You'll need a compile-time statement, and everything must be written in the code before running it.

Comment: Thank you! What does this mean exactly ? (j ? 1 : -1)

Comment: @MM. Well technically there is a way, it's just a very complicated way that is definitely overkill in this situation. (See JIT compilers written in C++, for example.)

Comment: @Pao `?:` is the ternary operator. It takes the form `conditional ? if_true : if_false`. If `conditional` evaluates as true, then the expression evaluates to `if_true`, otherwise it evaluates to `if_false`. Note that only one of `if_true` and `if_false` actually gets evaluated when the entire expression is evaluated, because when `conditional` is true for example, there is no need to evaluate the `if_false` expression.

Comment: @cdhowie: None of those compilers are the standard C++

Comment: @MM. No but they might be *written in* C++. In that case you have C++ code generating new code from some bytecode at runtime. I'm only using that as an example to illustrate that runtime code generation is possible in C++, but it's overly-complicated for this scenario, and it depends on the semantics of the architecture it gets executed on. (That is, it's non-portable.)

Answer (score 2):

C++ has no native facilities for runtime code generation. You could of course invoke a C++ compiler from your program, then dynamically load the resulting binary, and call code from it, but I doubt this is the best solution to your problem.

*If you are worried about repeatedly checking the condition, you shouldn't be.* Modern CPUs will likely deal with this very well, even in a tight loop, due to branch prediction.

---

Last, if you really want to more dynamically alter the code path you take, you could use function pointers and/or polymorphism and/or lambdas.

#### An example with functions

```
typedef void (pFun*)(int);    // pointer to function taking int, returning void

void b(int i){i+1}
void c(int i){i-1}

...

pFun d = cond ? b : c;        // based on condition, select function b or c


...
pFun(i);   // calls either b or c, effectively selecting + or -
```

---

#### An example with polymorphism

```
class Operator
{
public:
  Operator() {}
  virtual ~Operator() {}

  virtual void doIt(int i) = 0;
};

class Add : public Operator
{
public:
  virtual void doIt(int i) { i+1; }
};

class Sub : public Operator
{
public:
  virtual void doIt(int i) { i-1; }
};

...

Operator *pOp = cond ? new Add() : new Sub();
...
pOp->doIt(i);
...
delete pOp;
```

Here, I have defined a base class with the `doIt` pure virtual function. The two child classes override the `doIt()` function to do different things. `pOp` will then point at either an `Add` or a `Sub` instance depending on `cond`, so when `pOp->doIt()` is called, the appropriate implementation of your operator is used. Under the covers, this does essentially what I outlined in the above example with function pointers, so choosing one over the other is largely a matter of style and/or other design constrains. They should both perform just as well.

---

#### An example with lambdas

This is basically the same as the first example using function pointers, but done in a more C++11 way using lambdas (and it is more concise).

```
auto d = cond ? [](int i) { i+1; }
              : [](int i) { i-1; };
...
d(i);
```

Alternatively, you may prefer to have the condition inside the body of the lambda, for example

```
auto d = [&](int i) { cond ? i+1 : i-1; }
...
d(i);
```

Comment: Would it also be useful to show how to do this using lambda expressions?

Comment: @sjdowling Good idea since this is C++11. give me a minute.

Comment: Have you tried it with lambdas?  Your first example won't compile, since the second and third operands of the conditional operator don't have a common type.  (Every lambda has a unique type.)  (And the second example ends up making the test every time.)

Comment: An update concerning the lambdas: according to the standard (I'm actually looking at N3797; these things change so often), your first example with lambda shouldn't compile.  It doesn't, under VS 2013.  But it does with g++ 4.8.3 (with `--std=c++11`, of course).  This looks like a bug in g++, however.

Comment: @James Oh? That's a surprise. I don't actually work with lambdas much so I don't know the intricacies. Do you know what the problem is and how to correct it?

Comment: @SchighSchagh The issue is not lambdas per se.  It is due to the fact that each lambda creates a new, unique type, and that in a conditional expression, `a ? b : c`, either `b` must be convertible to the type of `c`, or `c` must be convertible to the type of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have runtime code generation since it's a compiled language.
In this case, you could put the sign into a variable (to be used with multiple variables.)
E.g.

```
int sign = (true ? 1 : -1);
result2 += sign;
result1 += sign;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily a solution for your problem, but you could use
a template, instantiated on one of the operators in `<functional>`:

```
template <typename Op>
int
func( int i )
{
    return Op()( i, 1 );
}
```

In your calling function, you would then do something like:

```
int (*f)( int i ) = condition ? &func<std::plus> : &func<std::minus>;
//  ...
i = f( i );
```

It's possible to use lambdas, which may be preferable, but you can't use
the conditional operator in this case.  (Every lambda has a unique type,
and the second and third operatands of the conditional operator must
have the same type.)  So it becomes a bit more verbose:

```
int (*f)( int i );
if ( condition ) {
    f = []( int i ) { return i + 1; }
} else {
    f = []( int i ) { return i - 1; }
}
```

This will only work if there is no capture in the lambdas; when there is
no capture, the lambda not only generates an instance of a class with
a unique type, but also a function.  Although not being able to use the
conditional operator makes this more verbose than necessary, it is still
probably simpler than having to define a function outside of the class,
unless that function can be implemented as a template, as in my first
example.  (I'm assuming that your actual case may be significantly more
complicated than the example you've posted.)

EDIT:

Re lambdas, I tried:

```
auto f = c ? []( int i ) { return i + 1; } : []( int i ) { return i - 1; };
```

just out of curiosity.  MSC++ gave me the expected error
message:

```
no conversion from 'someFunc::<lambda_21edbc86aa2c32f897f801ab50700d74>' to 'someFunc::<lambda_0dff34d4a518b95e95f7980e6ff211c5>'
```

but g++ compiled it without complaining, `typeid(f)` gave `"PFiiI"`,
which I think is a pointer to a function.  In this case, I'm pretty sure
that MSC++ is right: the standard says that each of the lambdas has
a unique type, and that each has a *conversion operator* to (in this
case) an `int (*)( int )` (so both can be converted to the same
type—this is why the version with the `if` works).  But the
specification of the conditional operator requires that either the
second operand can be converted to the type of the third, or vice versa,
but the results must be the type of one of the operands; it cannot be
a third type to which both are converted.